# How can I update the state correctly on change event for form type=range, it gives the previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, state, onchange

I want to pass the updated state in the url after a change event in handle change function.

It is passing the previous state instead of giving it the current updated state.

For example, the state value loan duration is 13 but when I console log it, it shows 12. When I change the loan amount it shows 3058 but I log 3016,  which is the previous state.

Please help

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    loanAmount: "500",
    loanDuration: "6"

  };

  handleChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.loanAmount, this.state.loanDuration);

    axios
      .get(
        `https://ftl-frontend-test.herokuapp.com/interest?
        amount=${this.state.loanAmount}&numMonths=${this.state.loanDuration}`
      )
      .then(resp => {
        this.props.onChange(resp.data);
        this.setState({ loanAmount: this.state.loanAmount, loanDuration: this.state.loanDuration });
      });
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <>
        <form onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <div className="amount form-control">
            <label htmlFor="formControlRange">Loan Amount  </label>

            <span className="rangeAmount">{this.state.loanAmount}</span>
            <input
              type="range"
              className="amountInput form-control-range"
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({
                  loanAmount: event.target.value
                })}

              value={this.state.loanAmount}

              min="500"
              max="5000"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
        <form onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <div className="duration form-control">
            <label htmlFor="formControlRange">Loan Duration  </label>

            <span className="rangeDuration">{this.state.loanDuration}</span>
            <input
              type="range"
              className="amountInput form-control-range"
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({
                  loanDuration: event.target.value,
                })}
              value={this.state.loanDuration}


              min="6"
              max="24"
            />
          </div>

        </form >
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because we can't get state immediately after doing setState. It is the functionality of React. You better use componentDidUpdate which is a part of React lifecycle which invoked when there is a update in the component.

You can change the code like this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
  import axios from "axios";

class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    loanAmount: "500",
    loanDuration: "6"
  };

  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    if(prevState.loanAmount !== this.state.loanAmount || prevState.loanDuration !== this.state.loanDuration) {
      console.log(this.state.loanAmount);
      console.log(this.state.loanDuration);

    axios
       .get(
         `https://ftl-frontend-test.herokuapp.com/interest?
         amount=${this.state.loanAmount}&numMonths=${this.state.loanDuration}`
       )
       .then(resp => {
         this.props.onChange(resp.data);
         this.setState({ loanAmount: this.state.loanAmount, loanDuration: this.state.loanDuration });
       });


  };

  render() {

    return (
      <>
        <form>
          <div className="amount form-control">
            <label htmlFor="formControlRange">Loan Amount  </label>

            <span className="rangeAmount">{this.state.loanAmount}</span>
            <input
              type="range"
              className="amountInput form-control-range"
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({
                  loanAmount: event.target.value
                })}

              value={this.state.loanAmount}

              min="500"
              max="5000"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
        <form>
          <div className="duration form-control">
            <label htmlFor="formControlRange">Loan Duration  </label>

            <span className="rangeDuration">{this.state.loanDuration}</span>
            <input
              type="range"
              className="amountInput form-control-range"
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({
                  loanDuration: event.target.value,
                })}
              value={this.state.loanDuration}


              min="6"
              max="24"
            />
          </div>

        </form >
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It is working but there is a small issue, it keeps on console logging the amount and duration do you have a way to stop that. Because it takes a lot of time to return the values I want.

Comment: Ohh, I got it prevProps will be the first argument and prevState the second. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, I got wrong in prevState and prevProps positions. I use auto-complete functions definitions. So it can happen. I edited the answer, please accept it as a answer. So it helps me improve my profile. Thank you.

Comment: It's updated automatically. It didn't ask me for any kind of approval. Keep answering ^_^